# How to execute/write all characteristics in a loop in ble in android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

How to write all writeCharacteristics in a loop in ble in android.code is as follows
in this method i pass 3 `writecharacteristic()` and only one is write and others are ignored.

```
if (beartoggle.isChecked()) {
    if (mDeviceLight.equalsIgnoreCase("on") && mDeviceAlarm.equalsIgnoreCase("on")) {
        byte[] val = {1};
        if (check_port_1 == 1) {
            mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val, 1);    
        }

        if (check_port_2 == 1) {
            mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val, 2);
        }
        if (find_me == 1) {
            mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val, 3);
        }

    }
}
```

and someone is saying use  **public void onReliableWriteCompleted()** and check if port1 is written then go to port2 and then findme. This method will help me, if yes then how ? Please send me clear details and following is my writeCharacteristic()

```
 public boolean writeCharacteristic(byte value[], int type) {

     //check mBluetoothGatt is available
     if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
         Log.e(TAG, "lost connection");

         return false;
     }
     BluetoothGattService Service = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID_SIMPLESERVICE);
     if (Service == null) {
         Log.e(TAG, "service not found!");
         return false;
     }
     BluetoothGattCharacteristic charac1 = null;
     BluetoothGattCharacteristic charac2 = null;
     BluetoothGattCharacteristic charac3 = null;
     boolean status1 = false, status2 = false, status3 = false;
     Log.v("___TYPE___", "________1______________" + (type == 1));
     Log.v("___TYPE___", "________2______________" + (type == 2));
     Log.v("___TYPE___", "________3______________" + (type == 3));
     onReliableWriteCompleted(status1);
     onReliableWriteCompleted(status2);
     onReliableWriteCompleted(status3);
     if (type == 1) {
         charac1 = Service.getCharacteristic(UUID_PORT1);
         charac1.setValue(value);
         status1 = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(charac1);
         Log.v("________BLESERVICE____", "___WRITE CHARATERISTICS STATUS:_________" + status1);
         onReliableWriteCompleted(status1);
     } else if (type == 2) {
         charac2 = Service.getCharacteristic(UUID_PORT2);
         charac2.setValue(value);
         status2 = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(charac2);
         onReliableWriteCompleted(status2);
         Log.v("________BLESERVICE_______", "___WRITE CHARACTERISTICS STATUS_______" + status2);

     } else if (type == 3) {
         charac3 = Service.getCharacteristic(UUID_FINDME);
         charac3.setValue(value);
         status3 = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(charac3);
         onReliableWriteCompleted(status3);
         Log.v("__________BLESERVICE_________", "___WRITE CHARACTERISTICS STATUS_____" + status3);
     }

     if (charac1 == null && charac2 == null && charac3 == null) {
         Log.e(TAG, "char not found!");
         return false;
     }

     Log.v("___TYPE___", "______________________" + type);
     return status1 && status2 && status3;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

call `BluetoothLeService.getSupportedGattServices()`, you will get a list of services. Iterate through it and call `BluetoothGattService.getCharacteristics()`. You will again get a list, you can iterate through it.

For more info, you can refer [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html)

Comment: how i didnot get it.i am new to this ble.

Comment: This is how you can iterate through each characteristic. You can refer the link for more detail or ask specific question regarding your problem

Comment: in the above condition only one  mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val, 1);  is written and remaining skips but i am getting status true for all 3  mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(). why what to do.

Comment: You should add some more snippet. What I can guess is, instead of "check_port_2 == 1", you might intend to write "check_port_2 == 2"

Comment: ok i am soryy,this is integer and i intialise as 0.and i did as follows if(uuid.equalsIgnoreCase(SampleGattAttributes.PORT2_CHARACTERSITIC.toString())){
                      
                      
                      check_port_2=1;
                        
                      if(port1.isChecked())
                      {   
                        Log.d("________________checked", "yes"+port2.isChecked());
                     }

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23005637/how-to-fill-the-color-of-image-according-to-percentage-of-textview-in-android/23005844?noredirect=1#comment35138813_23005844