# how to fill the color of image according to percentage of textview in android

Tags: android

How to fill the image according to percentage of textview.and it should change according to percentage of textview.below is my code so please check.

```
              private void displayData(String data) {
    if (data != null) { 
        battery.setText(data);
    }
    }
```

this is my textview i am getting data as 100 or some 60 like that.what ever value i got that much level my imageview should fill with color and display.

```
             <TextView  android:id="@+id/batterylevel"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="150dp" android:text="BRV Battery"  android:layout_below="@+id/sos"/>

  <ImageView 
      android:id="@+id/image_level"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/batterylevel"
android:layout_below="@+id/sos"
android:layout_above="@+id/portbearmode"

android:alpha="1"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"

 android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
```

in the layout i did like this i should apply any animations or simply setting any options please tell me.
if battery textview is 60 it should fill blue color upto 60 and remaining 40 as white color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following my method to get the battery percentage and pass that value to imagelevel button to display level.

```
          private void displayData(String data) {
    Log.v("______________________No serives_______________",data );
    if (data != null) { 
        battery.setText(data);
        int x=Integer.parseInt(battery.getText().toString());
     image_level.getLayoutParams().height =  x*2;
        Log.v("______BATERY LEVEL_________", "__IN DISPLAYDATA()___DCA__________"+data);
    }
```

and the following code is in layout to display.

```
               <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/image_layout"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"

android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayout"
  android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
>
      <Button
      android:id="@+id/image_level"
android:layout_width="100dp"
 android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#8099FFFF"
 android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

if u want to change the opacity then you can simply set the opacity according to the value in textview usinf setalpha method.

I have a good idea to solve this simply try it your self.

Put your imageview in a linear/relative layout set the heightto the max width that u want to assign for the image view.

Then initially set the heightof the image view to zero

Then depending on the value from textview set the height of the image view programatically

```
 int x=Integer.parseInt(battery.getText().toString());

 image_level.getLayoutParams().height = x;
```

Comment: i want to fill color as how much value i got in above textview in image.please add code so that it helps me.

Comment: actually how u want it change the opacity or filling color from left to right

Comment: same as like battery level how much percentage it shows that much level it should fill with blue color.

Comment: u want to fill the colour vertically or horizontally

Comment: read my answer carefully and change the height according to the input parameters

Comment: how to do see in the display() i should set imageview.setbackgroud(textview); like this or what say na

Comment: how to fill the color i added static as 60 to check but it is same and i put background as some color it was not showing.

Comment: see this image  http://iut.stack.imgur.com/uxO83.png it is circle.but they draw image but i had image at present i added default image later i will get image but my aim is to set color level to image what i got in textview.please help.

Comment: it was changing whole the layout but layout should not change only the filled color should change  upto the value and remaining null

Comment: hi arun check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23009657/how-to-change-the-image-color-in-imageview-according-to-percentage-and-fill-colo

Comment: hi arun,please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23053164/how-to-save-toggle-button-state-to-database-and-if-user-edits-then-edited-state

Comment: hi arun please check this link it is urgent task for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23076353/how-to-notify-characteristics-for-every-5secs-and-update-in-android

Answer (score 0):

See the now i hardcoded u can change it to dynamic

```
package com.example.testapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button image_level;
EditText battery_level;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 battery_level = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.batterylevel);
    image_level = (Button) findViewById(R.id.image_level);
    battery_level.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            if(!battery_level.getText().toString().equals("")){
 x =                   Integer.parseInt(battery_level.getText().toString());
            }
            image_level.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (1.5 * x);

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });

}


}
```

now the xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/batterylevel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sos"
     android:inputType="number"
    android:text="10" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/portbearmode"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sos"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/batterylevel"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/image_level"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: hi arun this not see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23010806/how-to-scale-the-image-color-according-to-value/23010916?noredirect=1#23010916

Comment: this code i added.but arun it is changing layout and if add  android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" the image in this also moves to small if x value changes.not like that on image only the level of color should change.

Comment: u want to give color?

Comment: yes.see suppose if a image is there i will get some value think that value as 60.then upto 60% of image should fill with that color.it like  if u touch tom face then smile icon fills the percentage like that and similar to battery level.

Comment: and i will get the level of battery and i am setting that data to textview.it level will be 0 to 100 only.means how much it charge that much i will get for this i am using ble services.so we have to set that value to the level of image with some color.like water in glass.

Comment: i tried but image also becoming small when it was 40

Comment: add the image as background of relative layout

Comment: arun did u got my question

Comment: and color to that filling where to add

Comment: as i did ,in button background

Comment: <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/image_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayout"
      android:background="#ffffff"
    >
          <ImageView 
          android:id="@+id/image_level"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#ff0000"
     android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
     
         </RelativeLayout>

Comment: i did as above but layout completely fills white color and image is invisible and level of color also not showing.

Comment: image view can't set background colour on run time so i used a button u try with button  also make sure relative layout width to wrapcontent

Comment: <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/image_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" >

Comment: ok arun but actually in presentation i saw battery image filled with blue color how much value it gots that much.if i add button it will be good and how can i show image as batery.

Comment: no arun. <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/image_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayout"
      android:background="#66BBCC"
    >
          <Button
          android:id="@+id/image_level"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#ff0000"
     android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
     
         </RelativeLayout>

Comment: i did like this and i set  image_level.getLayoutParams().height = x;

Comment: only relative layout color is filled and image is not visible

Comment: dont ask any question again

Comment: hi arun i am sorry.but when i give image_level.getLayoutParams().height = 100;

Comment: i got 50% of layout one color and 50% other color.

Comment: but my battery charge is max 100 only if 100 means it should fill whole and 50 means half only.

Comment: 150 =fill parent put 150,see my entire java code its a working example u can simply copy the code and run

Comment: ya its same 100*1.5 gives fulland 50*1.5 gives half

Comment: ok i will try and my time over.i will meet u on monday happy weekend.and sorry to disturb u.

Comment: hi arun, very gd mrg.i try and did like the following with ur coding and image is not visible y.

Comment: hi, i got image also visible see my answer.

Comment: hi arun,if u r free check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23052877/how-to-add-progress-bar-or-look-like-similar-one-in-android