# how to scale the image color according to value

Tags: android

How to fill the image according to percentage of `TextView`. and it should change according to percentage of `TextView` .in the following code the height layout is changing but i want the color of image should change according to percentage(value of textview(battery)).

**CODE:**

```
 private void displayData(String data) {
    if (data != null) { 
        battery.setText(data);
  int x=Integer.parseInt(battery.getText().toString());
  image_level.getLayoutParams().height = x;
    }
 }
```

This is my `TextView` i am getting data as 100 or some 60 like that.what ever value i got that much level my `ImageView` should fill with color and display.

```
<TextView  android:id="@+id/batterylevel"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="150dp"
 android:text="BRV Battery" 
 android:layout_below="@+id/sos"/>

<ImageView 
 android:id="@+id/image_level"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="100dp"
 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 

 android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
```

in the layout i did like this i should apply any animations or simply setting any options please tell me.
if battery `TextView` is 60 it should fill blue color upto 60 and remaining 40 as white color.

Comment: no arun.in below code i got error

Comment: y u have not tried the answer that i given. if u r not specific or u dont have any idea how to do it please ignore it. and dont disturb the people.First up all u should need a clear idea how to do this and try at your side? then ask doubts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following my method to get the battery percentage and pass that value to imagelevel button to display level.

```
          private void displayData(String data) {
    Log.v("______________________No serives_______________",data );
    if (data != null) { 
        battery.setText(data);
        int x=Integer.parseInt(battery.getText().toString());
     image_level.getLayoutParams().height =  x*2;
        Log.v("______BATERY LEVEL_________", "__IN DISPLAYDATA()___DCA__________"+data);
    }
```

and the following code is in layout to display.

```
               <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/image_layout"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"

android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayout"
  android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
>
      <Button
      android:id="@+id/image_level"
android:layout_width="100dp"
 android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#8099FFFF"
 android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Clip drawable.

See here :

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Clip

For instance in your code :

```
private void displayData(String data) {
    if (data != null) { 
        battery.setText(data);
  int x=Integer.parseInt(battery.getText().toString());
  ClipDrawable drawable = (ClipDrawable) image_level.getDrawable();
    drawable.setLevel(100 * x);
    }
 }
```

In your layout :

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_level"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/clip"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

And for your drawable/clip.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<clip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@color/myBlueColor"
    android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="left" />
```

And for your myBlueColor in colors.xml :

```
<color name="myBlueColor">#0383f3</color>
```

Comment: Which error do you get ? This is approximate code to give you an idea of how to do it. For instance the ImageView must be called image_level and not image

Comment: Could you please give me the stack trace of the error ?

Comment: 04-11 06:01:05.425: E/AndroidRuntime(7852):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1041)
04-11 06:01:05.425: E/AndroidRuntime(7852):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-11 06:01:05.425: E/AndroidRuntime(7852): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-11 06:01:05.425: E/AndroidRuntime(7852):  at com.incipio.brv_powerbank.DeviceControlActivity.displayData(DeviceControlActivity.java:550)

Comment: 04-11 06:01:05.425: E/AndroidRuntime(7852): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.incipio.brv_powerbank.DeviceControlActivity$2@43157908
04-11 06:01:05.425: E/AndroidRuntime(7852):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:778)

Comment: I think the error was on the ImageView, I modified the sample, please try again with that

Comment: hi yves, i done but i got only a thin line from left to center of screen and image is also not visible.

Comment: <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/image_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayout"
      android:background="#ffffff"
    >
         <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_level"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:src="@drawable/clip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="200dp" 
     android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
              </RelativeLayout>

Comment: Hello, you can modify that with android:layout_height and android:layout_width properties. See my new example

Comment: hi yves,very gd mrg.i solved my problem by above answer.urs also good but i got only single line so i try like above.please check it.

Comment: It is a bit hard for my answer, as I made the main part of the work and you were able to write your solution from mine. The main goal of this forum is to get help, not to get all the work done. At least could you upvote my answer please ?

Comment: ok yves i will vote but i did like i uploaded.but i am sorry itry u answer also.

Comment: hi yves,if u r free and dont mind please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23053164/how-to-save-toggle-button-state-to-database-and-if-user-edits-then-edited-state

Comment: hi yves r u happy and thanks to help me.please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23053164/how-to-save-toggle-button-state-to-database-and-if-user-edits-then-edited-state

Comment: Yes, I just gave a look to your other problem, but I do not have much time. I hope the comment I made will help

Comment: then wht about remaining thing yves i should get name,address,and 2 toggle buttons state.so retriving these all and in middle of app it should check with address and retrive those values only.so i done using database.

Comment: hi yves,i added screenshot please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23053164/how-to-save-toggle-button-state-to-database-and-if-user-edits-then-edited-state

Comment: hi yves please check and answer the above link i added screenshot also.later if u free please help me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50599/discussion-between-user3467237-and-yves-delerm)

Comment: hi yves, if u free please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23052877/how-to-add-progress-bar-or-look-like-similar-one-in-android

Comment: hi yves if u free please check this link it is urgent task for me so please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23076353/how-to-notify-characteristics-for-every-5secs-and-update-in-android

Comment: hi yves where i have to modify or still u want more code say to me

Answer (score -1):

Create layer-list in your drawable folder like this

doubleshade.xml

```
<item android:drawable="@color/white"/> 
<item android:right="60dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

In your code apply this shape according to the condition

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        int per = Integer.parseInt(textview.getText().toString());
        if(per >= 60 )
        {
         img.setImageResource(R.drawable.doubleshade);
        }
```

Comment: I think he is not asking only for 60 but for all different values.

Comment: i think i can edit my question after getting his feedback on this?

Comment: Yes, you can. I also can edit my vote if I consider your answer match the question. Currently, it does not.

Comment: Thanks for your vote. I am here, may be i can help someone, not for someone vote.

Comment: I know, but in my opinion, giving an answer to a wrong problem is not an help, but a potential loss of time for the person which would try your answer. That is the sense of the vote, telling whether somebody is answering the question or not.