# how to save toggle button state to database and if user edits then edited state should be saved to database in android

Tags: android

how to save toggle button state to database and if user edits then edited state should be saved to database in android.the following is my code it is working fine.but the problem is that when user edits to **on** it is in on state and **green light** displays on toggle button. and then user performs the required actions.when user again comes back to edit again it displays **on** only but **no green light** is visible.so it looks bad so please help me and following is my code.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.edit_layout);
                edittext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.device_text);
                light=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.light);
                alarm=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.alarm);
                db = new DataBaseAdapter(this);

                 Intent i = getIntent();


                   if(i.hasExtra("Dname"))
                         val = i.getStringExtra("Dname");


                   if(i.hasExtra("Dlight"))
                   slight=i.getStringExtra("Dlight");
                   blight=Boolean.valueOf(slight);


                   if(i.hasExtra("Dalarm"))
                   salarm=i.getStringExtra("Dalarm");
                   balarm=Boolean.valueOf(balarm);
                if(i.hasExtra("Daddress"))
                    pos=i.getStringExtra("Daddress");


              db.open();                  
              db.insertData(pos,val,slight,salarm);

                 c = db.getData();
                 edittext.setText(val);
                 light.setText(slight);
                // light.setChecked(blight);
                 alarm.setText(salarm);
                 //alarm.setChecked(balarm);

                    db.close();
             }


                @Override
                public void onBackPressed(){
                    db.open();
                    c=db.getData();

                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {


                                String strSQL = "UPDATE DeviceDetails SET devicename ='"+ edittext.getText().toString() +"'  WHERE uuid = '"+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("uuid"))+"'" ;
                                db.select(strSQL);

                                slight=light.getText().toString();
                                salarm=alarm.getText().toString();


                                if(pos.equalsIgnoreCase(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("uuid"))))
                                {
                                db.updateData(pos, edittext.getText().toString(),slight,salarm);
                                }

                           Intent intent=new Intent();
                            intent.putExtra("Dname", edittext.getText().toString());
                            intent.putExtra("Daddress",pos);
                            intent.putExtra("Dlight", slight);
                            intent.putExtra("Dalarm", salarm);
                            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                            finish();
                    } while (c.moveToNext());
                    }

                db.close();

                super.onBackPressed();
                }  
}
```

Comment: i wll suggest you to use shared prefrences to save state so that you can get rid of long code of entring and geting from db

Comment: it is good but while i open the app it should retrive the data from database.if it exits it should display that data otherwise null.so i used database.

Comment: @user3467237 please read the docs related to shared preferences. Did you know that the data in Shared Preference persists even if you re-started your device? The data in shared preference exists in Key-Value format which would be convenient for this scenario. For single value using SQLite is not really required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the following way i done and my problem solved.

```
                 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_layout);
    edittext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.device_text);
    light=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.light);
    alarm=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.alarm);
    db = new DataBaseAdapter(this);

     Intent i = getIntent();


       if(i.hasExtra("Dname"))
             val = i.getStringExtra("Dname");


       if(i.hasExtra("Dlight"))
       slight=i.getStringExtra("Dlight");
       blight=Boolean.valueOf(slight);


       if(i.hasExtra("Dalarm"))
       salarm=i.getStringExtra("Dalarm");
       balarm=Boolean.valueOf(balarm);

       Log.v("___EDIT CLASS____________", "__LIGHT TEXT_____________"+slight);
       Log.v("_____EDIT CLASS_____________", "___ALARM TEXT____________"+salarm);

       Log.v("___EDIT CLASS____________", "__LIGHT boolean_____________"+blight);
       Log.v("_____EDIT CLASS_____________", "___ALARM boolean____________"+balarm);


//  edittext.setText(val);
    if(i.hasExtra("Daddress"))
        pos=i.getStringExtra("Daddress");
  Log.v("___________edittext", "_______________"+edittext.getText());
  Log.v("__________address", "_______________"+pos);


  db.open();

  db.insertData(pos,val,slight,salarm);

     c = db.getData();
     edittext.setText(val);
     light.setText(slight);
    // light.setChecked(blight);
     alarm.setText(salarm);
     //alarm.setChecked(balarm);
     if(slight.equalsIgnoreCase("on"))
     {
         light.setChecked(true);
     }
     else

     {
         light.setChecked(false);
     }
     if(salarm.equalsIgnoreCase("on"))
     {
         alarm.setChecked(true);
     }
     else

     {
         alarm.setChecked(false);
     }
```

db.close();
        }

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        //saveData();
        db.open();
        c=db.getData();

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                   // slight=light.setClickable(true);
                    //salarm= String.valueOf(balarm); 

                    Log.v("_______BACK PRESSED", "______UUID___________"+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("uuid")));
                    Log.v("_______pos", "______UUID___________"+pos);
                    String strSQL = "UPDATE DeviceDetails SET devicename ='"+ edittext.getText().toString() +"'  WHERE uuid = '"+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("uuid"))+"'" ;
                    db.select(strSQL);
                    Log.v("___QUERY ", "_________________"+db.select(strSQL));
                    slight=light.getText().toString();
                    salarm=alarm.getText().toString();
                    Log.v("___EDIT CLASS____________", "__SLIGHT ___AFTER__________"+slight);
                    Log.v("_____EDIT CLASS_____________", "___SALARM ___AFTER_________"+salarm);

                    if(pos.equalsIgnoreCase(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("uuid"))))
                    {
                    db.updateData(pos, edittext.getText().toString(),slight,salarm);
                    }
                    /*Log.v("_______BACK PRESSED", "______UUID___________"+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("uuid")));
                    Log.v("_______cccccc", "______devicename___________"+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("devicename")));
                    Log.v("______EDIT IN DB", "______LIGHT___________"+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("light")));
                    Log.v("______EDIT IN DB", "______ALARM___________"+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("alarm")));
            */
            /*  Log.v("______device_____text", "_______________"+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("devicename")));
                Log.v("___________edittext", "_______________"+edittext.getText().toString());
                Log.v("_____ADDRESS______edittext", "_______________"+pos);
            */    Intent intent=new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("Dname", edittext.getText().toString());
                Log.v("_____edittext in intent________", "__________"+edittext.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("Daddress",pos);
                Log.v("_____edittext in intent________", "__________"+pos);
                intent.putExtra("Dlight", slight);
                intent.putExtra("Dalarm", salarm);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            /*  Log.v("_______EDIT IN DB", "______devicename___________"+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("devicename")));
                Log.v("______EDIT IN DB", "______LIGHT___________"+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("light")));
                Log.v("______EDIT IN DB", "______ALARM___________"+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("alarm")));
        */
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

    db.close();

    super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SharedPrefernce` for saving the state of toggle button.

```
sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Toggle_pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

editor.putInt("button_state", "state");

editor.commit();
```

Comment: then how can i save to database.it is good but while i open the app it should retrive the data from database.if it exits it should display that data otherwise null.so i used database.

Comment: Using SharedPreferences allows to save the data as well as SharedPreferences could do. While opening the app, you will only need to retrieve what you have store with this kind of code :         SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Toggle_pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        Integer buttonState = sharedpreferences.getInt("button_state", 0);

Answer (score 0):

This is code for Toogle Button with saved state..

```
    private SharedPreferences    spref;
    private ToggleButton tb;
    private boolean on;

    spref = getSharedPreferences("APP", MODE_PRIVATE);
            tb = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toogleButton);
            on = spref.getBoolean("On", true);  //default is true
            if (on) 
            {
              tb.setChecked(true);
            }       else
            {
              tb.setChecked(false);
            }

            tb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     if (tb.isChecked()) {
                            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "On : Notification will be Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = spref.edit();
                            editor.putBoolean("On", true); // value to store
                            editor.commit();

                        } else {
                       // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Off : Notification will be Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor =spref.edit();
                            editor.putBoolean("On", false); // value to store
                            editor.commit();
                        }  
                }
            });
```

Comment: hi guru,i have to save in database and retrive.